# How does light pass through rough glass?

Tags: optics, scattering, reflection, classical-electrodynamics

Light incident on a rough surface will be diffuse after passing it. Angular intensity depends on the grinding of the glass surface.

I'm trying to find information about the scattering indicatrix of light passing through the rough glass: how to calculate it numerically, which parameters are essential, etc., or at least where I should search for it. I would also be glad to find how to calculate it from the equations of electromagnetic fields.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE with this great question! Now you can upvote and mark an answer as helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of scattering, think of it as diffuse reflection. The [bidirectional reflectance distribution function (BRDF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BRDF) describes optical surface properties. It's application is as well in computer graphics, as in-depth ray tracing simulations. It depends on angle of incident light $\vec \omega_i$ (2 dimensions) and angle of observation $\vec \omega_r$, also 2 dimensional.

[image: Angles of BRDF function]

As the OP pointed out, it also depends on the method of surface grinding. If the grinding process is machined with linear strokes, it differs from sliding circular grinding. Finally the *BRDF* may depend on the spatial coordinates $\vec x$ on the surface.

Its dependance grows with a higher ratio of inhomogenity to laser spot diameter.
In total the rough glas surface may depend on 6 dimensions. The BRDF function
$$f(\vec \omega_i, \vec \omega_r, \vec x) = \frac{dL( \omega_r, \vec x)}{ dE(\omega_i)}$$
sets reflected light in amount in relation to incoming light. The differential out [radiance $L$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance) and incoming [irradiance $E(\omega_i)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irradiance) is the description of the rough glas surface.

*References to numerical models*

- Zheng Zhenrong et al., [Roughness characterization of well-polished surfaces by measurements of light scattering distribution](http://www.if.pwr.wroc.pl/~optappl/pdf/2010/no4/optappl_4004p811.pdf), Optica Applicata, Vol. XL, No. 4, 2010 Features BRDF of a silicon waver
- Hongsong Li et al., [An experimental study of the correlation between surface roughness
  and light scattering for rough metallic surfaces](http://www.graphics.cornell.edu/pubs/2005/LT05b.pdf), Proc. of SPIE 58780V-1, features actual **measurement data of rough ground glas**